# python, anaconda, Spyder -- uninstalling python package using pip DOES NOT work in Spyder + ipython

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, ipython, spyder

By using pip, I can successfully install new packages in ipython running in the Spyder environment. All I need to run is this:

```
!python -m pip install mypackage
```

However, trying to uninstall packages doesn't seem to work, at all. When I run:

```
!python -m pip uninstall mypackage
```

The console goes into a state of hanging. It's not strictly 'hanging' because neither Spyder nor the console hangs but the command just isn't returning anything

I am attaching a screenshot to help explain what I mean. The screenshot shows what happens AFTER I have pressed ENTER on this line - and nothing happens!

Does anything know why?

[image: pip uninstall.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

You should not use pip with Spyder. It can break your whole distribution. Spyder is part of the Anaconda package and you should use the conda command instead of pip. The conda command works similar to the pip command. Instead of pip install package you'd use conda install package.

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Both pip and conda are not meant to be run inside one of our IPython consoles because they expect to be running in a real system terminal (xterm, Terminal.app or cmd.exe).

In this case, pip expects input from the user (the confirmation that he/she really wants to uninstall a package). That confirmation can't be displayed in our consoles and it makes it looked like its blocked.

What you could do is to pass the `-q` option to pip to avoid confirmation. But in general it's a *very* bad idea to use pip and conda inside our consoles for the reasons I stated above.

Comment: Hi, Carlos, many thanks for your reply. It's good to get some insights from Spyder. Unfortunately your suggestion of using -q still doesnt' work. My new command is: "!python -m pip -q uninstall tensorflow". And it still hangs. I did try to use the native command line but 'pip' was not even recognized when I ran it on cmd. Must be environment variable issues but I don't know how to resolve it. Anyhow, the easist solution for me would still be to run pip on iPython (I know you advise against it) but -q doesn't help.

Comment: As I said, please stop using pip from our consoles and try to use it from the terminal. If it's not detected by default, you probably need to activate the conda or venv where you installed it first.

Answer (score 3):

I have a windows 10 64 bit machine, i installed spyder with `pip` and it could not work. so to uninstall i just used this command

```
pip uninstall spyder
```

however, if spyder has been installed with alongside Anaconda, Uninstalling Anacanda will delete its all packages including spyder.